# Why "no elements matching the key were found in the configuration element collection"?

Tags: c#, wcf-binding

I am programmatically creating a named pipe WCF service and client.

The service code does:

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CFCAccessPointService), new Uri(Names.Address));
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (ICfcAccessPoint), new NetNamedPipeBinding(Names.Binding), Names.Contract);
serviceHost.Open();
```

The client code:

```
var ctx = new InstanceContext(new StatusHandler());
s_proxy = new DuplexChannelFactory<ICfcAccessPoint>(ctx, new NetNamedPipeBinding(Names.Binding), new EndpointAddress(Names.Address));
```

with

```
public static class Names
{
    public const string Address = "net.pipe://localhost/CFC/Plugins/GuestAccessService";
    public const string Binding = "netNamedPipeBinding_ICfcAccessPoint";
    public const string Contract = "GuestAccessClientServerInterface.ICfcAccessPoint";
}
```

to ensure the client and service stay the same.

But if I drop the Names.Binding so that no binding configuration is specified, I get the error that no listener could be found at the endpoint.  If I include it, I get "no elements matching the key were found in the configuration element collection"...

I am not using .config files.

What is still missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binding was fine, either way, and in fact needed no argument at all.

The trouble was with the contract. When I changed to code to:

```
public static class Names
{
    public const string Address = "net.pipe://localhost/CFC/Plugins/GuestAccessService/";
    public const string Binding = "";
    public const string Contract = "CfcAccessPoint";
}
```

and on the service side:

```
this.serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICfcAccessPoint), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), Names.Contract);
```

and on the client side:

```
var ctx = new InstanceContext(this);
proxy = new DuplexChannelFactory<ICfcAccessPoint>(ctx, new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress(Names.Address) + Names.Contract);
```

then things worked fine.  The service just names the pipe; the client adds the address to the pipe name.

Voilá!

Answer (score 1):

It means that there is no binding with that name in your configuration file.  Since you have stated you are not using configuration files, this is not surprising.  Is there a reason that configuring your WCF endpoint in a web.config or app.config is not possible?  This is just my opinion, but I have found the configuration method far more flexible when I need to make random tweaks to the individual properties of my services.

Either way, the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585435(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `NetNamedPipeBinding(string)` constructor, the signature looks like this:

```
public NetNamedPipeBinding(
    string configurationName
)
```

This means that the only way to instantiate a `NetNamedPipeBinding` with this constructor requires that a binding with a name matching that string exist in your web.config or app.config files.  Which would look something like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netNamedPipeBinding>
            <binding name="netNamedPipeBinding_ICfcAccessPoint" />
        <netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

You are probably looking for the constructor which looks more like this:

```
public NetNamedPipeBinding(
    NetNamedPipeSecurityMode securityMode
)
```

Here is the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585437(v=vs.110).aspx) Link.

Using this constructor, your service host code would looke more like this:

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CFCAccessPointService), new Uri(Names.Address));
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (ICfcAccessPoint), new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), Names.Contract);
serviceHost.Open();
```

And your client code like this:

```
var ctx = new InstanceContext(new StatusHandler());
s_proxy = new DuplexChannelFactory<ICfcAccessPoint>(ctx, new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress(Names.Address));
```

This should avoid the need for config files.

Comment: Sorry, but neither suggestion worked. When I modified the code to set the security mode, I got the no listener error. Adding the config file made no difference at all.